# Typescript on Codepen

Tags: typescript, codepen

```
function greeter(person: string) {
  return "Hello, " + person;
}

let user:number[] = [0, 1, 2];

document.body.textContent = greeter(user);
```

This obviously faults in a normal editor, with: `Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.` but compiles fine on codepen: https://codepen.io/jmsherry/pen/oNNLNQQ?editors=0012. I can't see any compilation errors in any console, so I am very confused! Can anyone help?

Comment: Even though it has compilation error it still emits code https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwE4FN1XagFABxwGcEAuRIqVGMZASkQG8BYAKEQ8QyhFSQCIAEugA2IuABpE-RAGpEhVCTABuNgF82bEVkQgiOUmBABbAEY4A2gF1EAXkSWADFICMUgEzW1rNgBM4CFN0MCgAOjM4PwBPMOwADygAYQRsUPsUDCwcXH0cOhUgA So it's up to whoever runs `tsc` whether to stop there or consume the final js.

Comment: OK, but where is the error output to? The point of typescript is to check for these errors - what would be the point if you don't show them anywhere?

Comment: "what would be the point if you don't show them anywhere" ---  I don't use codepen. Would possible worth asking them.